# WiFi: Frequencies that map to non-overlapping 2.4 GHz channels 1,6 & 11

Tags: router, wifi, mikrotik, routeros, frequency

I'm configuring a wireless router. I know the non-ovelapping channels are 1,6 & 11.  However, my router only specifies ***frequencies*** that I can select, not ***channels***.  What are the frequencies that map to channels 1,6 & 11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to set your wireless radio in your router to a non-overlapping channel, the mapping of frequencies to non-overlapping channels for 2.4GHz is:

Freq:

```
2412  ==> Channel 1

2437  ==> Channel 6

2462  ==> Channel 11
```

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels)

MikroTik doesn't reference channels in ***RouterOS*** but frequencies only, so might help others configuring a router which only describes frequencies set the appropriate value correctly-

Answer (score 0):

we use 1-6-11 non-overlapping channels with 22MHz width DSSS modulation. DSSS modulation is used with channel speed 1-11Mbps. For higher channel speed OFDM modulation is used. OFDM modulation uses only 20MHz so there are 4 non-overlapping channels - 1-5-9-13 (2412-2432-2452-2472). But only if your client devices can use channel 13 :)